# Python: How can I find the average value for all rows with a value of n?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently trying to find the average value for all rows in which the YearsCode Value is one thing. My goal is to make it be that I have a graph which has the average Salary for every amount of time in which someone says they have coded.
For example, if I had a chart that had 5 rows in which the value of row x was n, then I would average all those values to one new column called 'Average Row with value n'.

The data which I am using is the results from the 2020 Stack Overflow Developers Survey.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('survey_results_public.csv') 

%matplotlib inline

df_new = df.copy()
df_new = df_new.drop(['Age1stCode','CompTotal','Respondent', 'MainBranch', 'Hobbyist', 'Age', 'CompFreq', 'Country', 'CurrencyDesc', 'CurrencySymbol', 'DatabaseDesireNextYear', 'DatabaseWorkedWith', 'DevType', 'EdLevel', 'Employment', 'Ethnicity', 'JobFactors', 'JobSat', 'JobSeek', 'LanguageDesireNextYear', 'LanguageWorkedWith', 'MiscTechDesireNextYear', 'MiscTechWorkedWith', 'NEWCollabToolsDesireNextYear', 'NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith', 'NEWDevOps', 'NEWDevOpsImpt', 'NEWEdImpt', 'NEWJobHunt', 'NEWJobHuntResearch', 'NEWLearn', 'NEWOffTopic', 'NEWOnboardGood', 'NEWOtherComms', 'NEWOvertime', 'NEWPurchaseResearch', 'NEWPurpleLink', 'NEWSOSites', 'NEWStuck', 'OpSys', 'OrgSize', 'PlatformDesireNextYear', 'PlatformWorkedWith', 'PurchaseWhat', 'Sexuality', 'SOAccount', 'SOComm', 'SOPartFreq', 'SOVisitFreq', 'SurveyEase', 'SurveyLength', 'Trans', 'UndergradMajor', 'WebframeDesireNextYear', 'WebframeWorkedWith', 'WelcomeChange', 'WorkWeekHrs', 'YearsCodePro'], axis = 'columns')
df_new = df_new.dropna()

df_woman = df_new.drop(index=df_new[df_new['Gender'] != 'Woman'].index, inplace=True)
df_woman = df_new
df_woman = df_woman.drop(['Gender'], axis ='columns')
```

That is my code so far.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data? I think you might want to use something like `df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean()` which will return the average salary per years coded.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Can you put that in as the answer?

Comment: Great - I have put it as an answer. Feel free to mark it as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: How can I sort the results in the YearsCode list from average_salaries = df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean(). I have tried average_salary.sort_values(), but that sorted the 'Salary' column. How can I specify for it to sort the 'YearsCode' column?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use

```
df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean()
```

This will return the average salary per years coded.

To sort the result by `'YearsCode'` you can use `sort_index`

```
df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean().sort_index()
```

To sort the result by the average salary you can use `sort_values`

```
df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean().sort_values('Salary')
```

Comment: For some reason when I do df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean().sort_index(), nothing happens. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @Victoria Unfortunately, it's hard to tell without your data and desired output. Is the resulting index not sorted?

Comment: Yes,the resulting index  is not sorted. Only the Salary column is

Comment: @Victoria Did you update your dataframe? Either `df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean().sort_index(inplace=True)` or `df = df.groupby('YearsCode')['Salary'].mean().sort_index()`?

Comment: Oh, I figured out my problem, thanks for the help!